# Rstudio viewer pane keeps looking for index.html in self contained document

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown

I compiled a bookdown's **single document** using `bookdown::gitbook()`. The resulting file is one HTML document at `_book/projectname.html` but the Rstudio viewer pane shows `"_book/index.html not found"` although the window header and the file name displayed before "Open in Browser" shows the correct file name. If I click on "Open in Browser", the correct HTML file is displayed in my default web browser.

Here is how I did that hopefully it could be reproduced. I created a new bookdown project using the default skeleton (A Minimal Book Example), added "`split_by: none`" and "`self_contained: true`" in `_output.yml`, and built the book using Build window using bookdown::gitbook.

I don't know if it's helpful but here is the result of my `xfun::session_info("bookdown")`. Thank you.

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362), RStudio 1.2.1335

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
  LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3  bookdown_0.13    digest_0.6.20    evaluate_0.14   
  glue_1.3.1       graphics_3.6.1   grDevices_3.6.1  highr_0.8       
  htmltools_0.3.6  jsonlite_1.6     knitr_1.24       magrittr_1.5    
  markdown_1.1     methods_3.6.1    mime_0.7         Rcpp_1.0.2      
  rmarkdown_1.15.1 stats_3.6.1      stringi_1.4.3    stringr_1.4.0   
  tinytex_0.15     tools_3.6.1      utils_3.6.1      xfun_0.9        
  yaml_2.2.0
```

**Edit**: I found that running bookdown::gitbook() in Console creates correct HTML file without automatically displaying it in the Viewer pane. Therefore, this problem must be the problem of the Build Book feature in RStudio. RStudio source code is beyond my knowledge so I opened an [issue #5371](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5371) in the RStudio Github repo.

Comment: This sounds like a Rstudio issue. Have you tried e.g. latest [daily build](https://dailies.rstudio.com/)?

Comment: I tried both the preview and daily built versions. The problem persists.